# Highlight tab based on current route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a simple react app using react router with two routes. How do I highlight the active route? I have tried all possible solutions from stackoverflow and other sources.

[Here is a live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xl7689r83p)

Answer (score 3):

The `NavLink` component is having incorrect Link path, which doesn't match the Route path, You need to write your path like

```
<NavLink
     to="/about"
     activeClassName="acti"
>
```

Note the `/` before `about`

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/my3xrq2v48)**

Comment: Glad to have helped